# How to pass ArrayList<String> to String[] and display the value inside a Spinner?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, spinner

What I'm trying to do is the following, I've an `ArrayList<String>` which I populate with data, then I have a `String[]` that I'm using to display text on my spinner, so I want to put the data of my `ArrayList` inside to replace what's by default but nothing happens.

When I'm trying to display it without Arrays.toString() it gives me the following :

```
[Ljava.lang.string;@e4b348
```

But with the arrays.tostring() i get what i want.

So how to pass my data ArrayList inside my string[] to display it on spinner ?

Here is my code :

```
String prestationuserlist;
ArrayList<String> textfordropdown2 = new ArrayList<>();
String[] textfordropdown = {"test", "test", "test","test", "test", "test","test", "test", "test","test", "test", "test","test", "test", "test","test", "test", "test"};
String[] valueofdropdowtext = {"test", "test", "test"};
Spinner  spinnerdynamic;


for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++) {
   object = prestationlist.getJSONObject(i);
   // Here, we populate the array with value of json, each text and db value
   textfordropdown2.add(object.getString("Text"));
   valueofdropdown.add(object.getString("Value"));
   valueofdropdowtext = valueofdropdown.toArray(new String[0]);
   textfordropdown = textfordropdown2.toArray(new String [textfordropdown2.size()]);

}
```

My spinner :

```
    //Start Create a spinner with different view and value.
    spinnerdynamic = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, textfordropdown );// Here we set the text with API return value.
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);// Here we create a dropdown list item.
    spinnerdynamic.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinnerdynamic.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1); // Here we call the function which is getting the value according to selected text.
    //End Create a spinner with different view and value.
```

Here is OnItemSelectedListener :

```
  OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
            new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
                    prestationuserlist = valueofdropdowtext[position];
                    test = textfordropdown[position];
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
            };
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Your question is not clear.

Comment: The problem is that my values "test" are not replaced by the values of the ArrayList<string> textfordropdown2

Comment: Why don't you pass the `ArrayList<String>` directly to the Adapter? Why you need to replace it ?

Comment: Because the displayed value and the real value of my dropdown element isn't the same. So if i pass my array the text is displayed but the values are not set and if i set values the text can't be set. See my updated code

Comment: I still did not get what's your concern. But if it is something like that you need to show some other value and on select choose some other value then you can combine the data in `bean` class and create a custom adapter for your spinner.

Comment: Well, my spinner have different value than the displayed text and the issue is that when i'm trying to display my text according to my value the value don't work and if i display something else and set the value it works.

Comment: You need a Hashmap for this, with <key,value> as <displayed value, actual value> pairs. Use the Hashmap  for onClick manipulation. 
And keep an arraylist (with displayed values) for display purposes only.

Comment: I'll look on this side so, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to convert your arrayList of Strings into an Array when using it with spinner adapter.**

See code below -

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // populate arraylist with data
    ArrayList<String> spinnerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        spinnerArrayList.add("Item " + i);
    }

    // create spinner adapter with the above arraylist
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArrayList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attach adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

This is what I get -

[image]

Comment: Yes, but since i'm making a treatment to have different display and value on my dropdown i'm not able to do that this way, if i pass the array i get my text but then the values are not setted anymore, other way i get values but can't display my text :/

Comment: In that case, you can use an arraylist to store "displayed values" and a hashmap to store "displayed values + actual values" as key value pairs. You can then get the actual value using Hashmap using something like this -

for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
    String displayedValue = entry.getKey();
    String actualValue = entry.getKey();
// use actual value
}

Comment: Use a bean or a HashMap to store the text for key and the value for value!

Comment: I'll try this way !

Answer (score 0):

Try this for convert Arraylist to array

```
String[] textfordropdown = arrayList.toArray();
```

and then  set it to Spinner like that

```
spinnerdynamic  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, textfordropdown ); 
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerdynamic.setAdapter(arrayAdapter );
```